Finding solution to the wave equation by the characteristics method
Given the wave equation in one spatial dimension, $\phi_{tt} -c^2\phi_{xx} = 0,$ setting $u:=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}, v := \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x},$ we get the matrix representation in the form $Ax = b,$ $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 &-c^2\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
u_x\\
v_x 
\end{pmatrix} = -\begin{pmatrix}
u_t\\
v_t
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Following the method of characteristics, the book I am reading finds the characteristics and thus the solutions to the system of linear equations by setting the eigen value problem, $(A^T - \lambda I)x = 0.$ I do not understand how one gets from Ax = b to the requirement that $(A^T - \lambda I)x = 0$ have to hold. In particular, why one needs to take the transpose ? I thought first, it might be related to the Fredholm alternative result $A^Ty = 0,$ in order to get a solution to $Ax = b$ above. Can one explain how to get from $Ax = b$ to the eigenvalue problem $(A^T - \lambda I)x = 0$ ? Thanks.

Too long for a comment.
Probably this condition is associated to the involved differential operators: calling
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &-c^2\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\ \ \ \ g =  \begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we have
$$
A g_x-g_t = 0
$$
Applying the Laplace transform
we get
$$
A \hat g_x - s \hat g = g(0,x)
$$
now, applying again the Laplace transform we have
$$
A z \tilde{\hat g}-s\tilde{\hat g} = \tilde{g}(0,z)-A z \tilde{\hat g}(s,0)
$$
or
$$
\left(Az-I_2 s\right)\tilde{\hat g} = \tilde{g}(0,z)-A z \tilde{\hat g}(s,0)
$$
then
$$
\tilde{\hat g} =\left(Az-I_2 s\right)^{-1}\left(\tilde{g}(0,z)-A z \tilde{\hat g}(s,0)\right)
$$
and
$$
\left(Az-I_2 s\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{s^2-c^2z^2}\begin{pmatrix}
s &c^2z\\
z & s
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note the eigenvalues $(s+c z)(s-c z) = 0$
